# How to access Kubernetes (Minikube or Docker Kubernetes) installed in a Windows 10 computer in my MacBook

Tags: windows-10, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am develping complex aplications in Kubernetes. My Mac only has 2 cores and 16 GB RAM. those 2 cores are a limitation when dealing with complicated deployments such us Hyperledger Fabric blockchain networks. I have a powerful gaming computer running Windows 10 and I have installed Docker and Minikube, but I can't access minikube from outside it (from my Macbook). I don't have much experience on windows and it does not look straightforward how to "expose" the Kunernetes APi to outside (I don't need to expose apps deployed in the Windows minikube; I just need to be able to access that minikube using kubectl runnin on my mac.

How can I have minikube (and which hypervisor to use) so it listens to the Wifi IP address? (Also for Docker Kubernetes, if not possible with minikube. Ideally I'd like to use minikube better)
How should I configure Windows 10 firewall to allow incoming requests from my MacBook kubectl?